# fast truthiness check / to-boolean conversion?

Tags: if-statement, boolean, jq

The [manual](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#if-then-else-end) talks about "truthiness" in the "if-then-else" section, defining everything besides `false` and `null` as `true`.

Is there a shorter way to check the truthiness of a filter `f` than a full-fledged if-then-else like this?

```
if f then true else false end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `not` filter also converts its input into boolean (under the same conditions, but negated), so if you want to have it shorter (and less readable), use it twice: `not|not`

```bash
null, false, true, 0, 1, [], {}, ""
| not | not
```

```json
false
false
true
true
true
true
true
true
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Ya_ahm93m0c)

---

Even shorter (and even less readable) would be to use the input for some boolean operations, like a disjunction with itself: `. or .` (for golfers: you could even omit the second space character):

```bash
null, false, true, 0, 1, [], {}, ""
| . or .
```

```json
false
false
true
true
true
true
true
true
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/08pyowUQBzK)

---

But seriously, just define a function yourself (most readably employing regular `if`), and then you can use that everywhere else instead:

```bash
def toboolean: if . then true else false end;

null, false, true, 0, 1, [], {}, ""
| toboolean
```

```json
false
false
true
true
true
true
true
true
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/jfxyeBSa_bf)

Answer (score 1):

See @pmf's answer re conversion to "boolean".  I'd just add that in practice it's rarely needed as a means to another end.

Re checking, you might find the following points useful:

1. In sufficiently recent versions of jq, `if COND then THEN else . end` can be abbreviated by dropping the `else` clause.
2. `select(COND)` is equivalent to `if COND then . else empty end` and is often handy.  Similarly for `select(COND) // WHATEVER`
3. You might like to take advantage of `//` in other contexts as well.